# Stop R turning text into scientific notation when importing data from SQL database

Tags: sql, r, rodbc, scientific-notation

I have had a solid google around and can only find methods to stop numbers appearing in scientific notation, but not text.

Onto the specifics of the problem.

I work a lot with fisheries data, which is often reported spatially to an ICES statistics rectangle ([For more information click here](http://www.ices.dk/marine-data/maps/Pages/ICES-statistical-rectangles.aspx)), the problem is that these rectangles are in this format: 28E5. This unfortunately causes R to convert the numbers into scientific format (28E5 = 2.8E^5), this is usually fine when working with CSV's as I have a little work around for it. However, in this project I am importing my data from an online database using the RODBC package, which means my work around for keeping the rectangles as text wont work as R handles these data first.

I have tried using the following line of code, however, this just causes R to turn 28E5 into 2800000.

```
options(scipen=999)
```

I cannot find any solution to this problem, any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't matter, I have just found a solution!!!!! Of course it was just after I posted the question. Use as.is = T in the sqlquerey function for anyone who has this problem in the future

Comment: Correction: use `as.is=TRUE` in that function. `T` is not a reserved keyword and can be overwritten: `T <- FALSE` actually works.